# Cant find sushiswap router address for Kovan testnet

Tags: kovan, uni

Can anyone get me a routerV2 address for sushiswap on Kovan? The address given on sushi page is incorrect.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x1b02dA8Cb0d097eB8D57A175b88c7D8b47997506, just verified it on etherscan.

Other addresses of Sushiswap contracts can be found here: https://dev.sushi.com/sushiswap/contracts